# Ubuntu Touch - root access without signing in

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-one, root, tablet

I got an Ubuntu tablet *because* I expected more freedom and control over my privacy. Now I [learn](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763419/can-i-install-apps-in-ubuntu-touch-without-signing-in) it is not quite like that. If this fails my expectation, the package ships right back...

Question: how to gain root access (terminal access and apt-get) without an Ubuntu One account?

To clarify: It's not that I wouldn't want the account. I don't want it on the tablet.

Comment: That answer tells me you can just install apps through the terminal, without needing an Ubuntu One account. I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: There's no terminal?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to install apps from the app store, because you don't want an Ubuntu One account, then you will have to build the packages from source and side-load them.

You can side-load an app if you have the click package for it, by putting the click on the device, and running `pkcon install-local --allow-untrusted foo.click` for example. You can use adb over USB to access the device and run these commands prior to installing the Terminal app.

You can also re-flash your device to the non-retail device images, which I believe have the Terminal app pre-installed.

Comment: This sounds very promising. Thank you. I'll give it a go

Comment: Hi, I haven't found any unofficial (non-retail) image for BQ Aquaris M10 FHD or do you mean the one offered on Ubuntu pages? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices Thanks.

Comment: Yes. The `ubuntu-touch/rc-proposed/ubuntu-pd` channel is available on cooler and frieza.

Comment: Hi @dobey, I have managed to re-install ubuntu from scratch using this tutorial: https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/ and I have adb shell access for sure so I'm root. I'm just wondering where to find the terminal click package (and other free sw click packages). Thanks, Rob